# Get Values from iframe url in PHP

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, parameters

I am using below iframe code in my website. In this iframe url i have to passes some values  and now i need to get all those values in my iframe website. How can i get it. I have tried  $_GET but its not working.

```
<iframe src="https://MYWEBSITE.com?p=user@gmail.com@q=papita" width="100%" height="300px">
```

I need to access p and q values on my https://MYWEBSITE.com all pages in PHP .

Comment: I think the problem is just the way you generated the `src` value. Between query parameters you should use the `&` char but you used `@`. Secondly, I would encode them with `urlencode()` and finally I think that the full value of an HTML attribute should be passed through `htmlentities()` leading to this: `src="https://MYWEBSITE.com?p=user%40gmail.com&amp;q=papita"`

Comment: `https://MYWEBSITE.com?p=user%40gmail.com&q=papita` will have $_GET["p"] contain the email address and $_GET["q"] contain papita